# Eclipse form based XML editor

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-plugin

Can anyone suggest me some reading for creating Form based editor in Eclipse?

Comment: "Ze goggles! Zey do nothing!" ...Sorry, I just had to ;) What do you mean by form-based editor? You mean you want to have a UI form that has edit fields for the XML elements?

Comment: Yeah just like Mainfest editor in eclipse. Though it's code is too complex too understand :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right Google term would probably be "Eclipse Forms", and there are a few articles available:

- [Eclipse Forms API - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseForms/article.html)
- [Revitalize your applications with Eclipse Forms](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-forms/index.html)
- [Eclipse Forms: Rich UI for the Rich Client](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html)

Also, in general a good place to start searching for Eclipse material is http://www.eclipse.org/articles/