# Eclipse Plugin to Handle a particular file self defined

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to find out how much effort it would be to create a Eclipse Plugin which can handle the editing of a particular file (our own format where the result might be XML). So i only need to do some editing stuff in the plugin. Drop-Down Boxes and some other fields might be interessting. I've seen something like this in the Maven Eclipse Plugin for the POM, but the document wouldn't be that complex.

Comment: This question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062775/eclipse-form-based-xml-editor

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i'm searching for.

Comment: Please delete your question then to prevent others from seeing it and seeing if they should answer it. :)