# How to create custom configuration editor plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I would like to create the configuration editor plugin for my XML configuration file which would be similiar to this.

[image: Configuration editor]

I was searching how I can create Eclipse plugin and I didn't find any plugin option which would allow me to do that. Only thing which is close to what I want is custom editor but it would be very tedious write entire configuration logic and I would like to use some existing tools.

Thank you for advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would have to create a custom editor using the forms API, see [Eclipse form based XML editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062775/eclipse-form-based-xml-editor/3073313#3073313)